# Is a power system acting in leading mode after power factor correction bad?

Tags: power, generator, power-factor-correction

I am modelling a simple power system with two generators.

The power system is initially assumed to be operating with a lagging pf (the generators are providing reactive power). However, some capacitors were added to the system for power factor correction, however, these capacitors turned out to be too large and over corrected the pf. Now the system operates in leading pf mode, the generators are now receiving reactive power.

I wanted to ask which situation is optimum for a system? Lagging, leading or unity pf? And is leading/lagging pf inherently bad? Therefore, is it worth reducing capacitor size such that the pf is lagging as most loads are inductive therefore, need reactive power?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `optimum for a system`?

Comment: For max efficiency of power transmission which pf would be best - I think unity, but not exactly sure why. @Andyaka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by `optimum for a system`?

> *For max efficiency of power transmission which pf would be best - I
> think unity, but not exactly sure why. @Andyaka – Tea_Cups*

For maximum power efficiency in the transmission of electrical power from a generator system to a load, the **power factor is unity**. This means that the current flowing through the transmission system is minimized as low as it can be and, the heat loss due to resistive wires in the transmission system is kept as low as it can be.

A leading or lagging power factor implies more current through the wiring than what is taken by the load and, that can never be good for efficiency.

In effect, the power factor correction capacitors act to "tune" the inductive load into parallel resonance. And, of course, parallel resonance presents the highest impedance it is able to the source and thus minimizes transmission current.

> *And is leading/lagging pf inherently bad?*

It can't be avoided a lot of the time so it shouldn't be regarded as bad.

Comment: I see that makes sense, but for a theoretical model, if pf can be made to unity, it should right?

Comment: `it should right?` if you mean it is optimized for minimum transmission losses then yes.